# Next.js Page component for loading props from getStaticProps

Tags: next.js

I have a page component that's supposed to render out a list. The list content is loaded from `/pages/api/latest.js`, and inside the `getStaticProps` function the fetch works as expected. However, sending the list items to the component does not work.

Here's a simplified version of my page:

```js
export default function Index({ questions }) {
    return (
        <>
            {questions?.length && (
                <ol>
                    {questions.map((item) => (
                        <li key={item.id}>
                            {item.title}
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ol>
            )}
        </>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const latestRequest = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/latest`);
    const latest = await latestRequest.json();

    const questions = latest.latest;
    console.log(questions);

    //  Terminal console output:
    //  [{ id: 64, title: 'commodo auctor velit' }, { id: 6, title: 'dui. Suspendisse ac' }]

    return { props: { questions } };
}
```

The console output looks fine. The list of questions, however, is not passed to the Index function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try to `console.log(questions);` in `Index` just to make sure it's passed to the function?

Comment: It's apparently `undefined`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it -- I had a typo in my `_app.js` page.

I had

```js
export default function MyApp({ Component, PageProps }) {
   return <Component {...PageProps} />
}
```

instead of

```js
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
   return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

I.E. **pageProps** was mistyped as **PageProps**.

Answer (score 0):

Your prop is set up slightly wrong. You need to have an identifier for each prop you pass.

Change

```
return { props: { questions } };
```

To this

```
return { props: { questions: questions } };
```

Comment: I've tried that, and still no dice...

Comment: Add a console.log(questions) inside your index function and let me know what the returns

Comment: It's apparently `undefined`...